# pass a collection instead of array to fetch().then() callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, promise, marionette, deferred

Module which fetches data from the server and returns a Promise

```
MedicineManager.module("Entities", function (Entities, MedicineManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Entities.Suggestion = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            suggestion: ""
        }
    });

    Entities.SuggestionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Entities.Suggestion,
        comparator: "suggestion"
    });

    var API = {
        getSuggestions: function (medicine) {
            var suggestions = new Entities.SuggestionCollection();
            suggestions.url="/medicine_suggestions/?id=" + medicine;
            return suggestions.fetch();
        }
    };

    MedicineManager.reqres.setHandler("suggestion:entities", function (medicine) {
        return API.getSuggestions(medicine);
    });

});
```

Module which calls the above module for getting fetched data

```
MedicineManager.module("MedicinesApp.Suggest", function (Suggest, MedicineManager,
    Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {


            MedicineManager.request("suggestion:entities", "paracetamol").then(function (medicines) {


            });
});
```

How do I get collection instead of an array as the parameter to the callback function in `then()` because the `medicines` parameter passed to the callback is giving an array after fetching the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly returning the xhr promise, [filter it via `.then`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to set your collection as the promised value :

```
var API = {
    getSuggestions: function (medicine) {
        var suggestions = new Entities.SuggestionCollection();
        suggestions.url="/medicine_suggestions/?id=" + medicine;
        return suggestions.fetch().then(function() {
            return suggestions;
        });
    }
};
```

The first argument (`medicines`) in `MedicineManager.request(...).then(function (medicines) { });` will be your collection.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the success callback along with options, which will be invoked with the collection as first argument by backbone:

```js
Entities.SuggestionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Entities.Suggestion,
  comparator: "suggestion"
});

var API = {
  getSuggestions: function(medicine, options) {
    var suggestions = new Entities.SuggestionCollection([],{
      url : "/medicine_suggestions/?id=" + medicine
    });
    return suggestions.fetch(options);
  }
};
 MedicineManager.reqrest.setHandler("suggestion:entities",API.getSuggestions);
```

Which you can use like:

```
MedicineManager.request("suggestion:entities", "paracetamol", {
  success: function(medicines) {}
});
```

Comment: how can I access `var suggestions` collection inside `success` function

Comment: @Flake first argument will be the collection. In the above code it's named medicines, you can change it to suggestions or anything you want